# Insert Picture into SQL Server 2005 Image Field using only SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, image

Using SQL Server 2005 and Management Studio how do I insert a picture into an `Image` type column of a table?

Most importantly how do I verify if it is there?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(50) not null,
    Photo varbinary(max) not null
)


INSERT INTO Employees (Id, Name, Photo) 
SELECT 10, 'John', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\photo.bmp', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture
```

Comment: It is important to note that the path listed is looked for on the SQL Server (not the querying machine).  So if your SQL Server is not your dev machine you will have to get your image referable from the SQL Server machine.

Comment: I have same data stored in MSSQL and exported into MySQL? What are steps to display with PHP?

Answer (score 41):

For updating a record:

```
 UPDATE Employees SET [Photo] = (SELECT
 MyImage.* from Openrowset(Bulk
 'C:\photo.bmp', Single_Blob) MyImage)
 where Id = 10
```

**Notes:**

- Make sure to add the 'BULKADMIN' Role Permissions for the login you are using.
- Paths are not pointing to your computer when using SQL Server Management Studio. If you start SSMS on your local machine and connect to a SQL Server instance on server X, the file C:\photo.bmp will point to hard drive C: on server X, not your machine!

Comment: How can I proceed if my image is stored locally and I want to insert into the remote DB?

Comment: Use a network share: UPDATE Employees SET [Photo] = (SELECT MyImage.* from Openrowset(Bulk '\\your-machine-name\Shared Folder\photo.bmp', Single_Blob) MyImage) where Id = 10

Answer (score 0):

Create Table:

```
Create Table EmployeeProfile ( 
    EmpId int, 
    EmpName varchar(50) not null, 
    EmpPhoto varbinary(max) not null ) 
Go
```

Insert statement:

```
Insert EmployeeProfile 
   (EmpId, EmpName, EmpPhoto) 
   Select 1001, 'Vadivel', BulkColumn 
   from Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\Image1.jpg', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture
```

This Sql Query Working Fine.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the goal where I have multiple images to insert in the DB as

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[User]
           ([Name]
           ,[Image1]
           ,[Age]
           ,[Image2]
           ,[GroupId]
           ,[GroupName])
           VALUES
           ('Umar'
           , (SELECT BulkColumn 
            FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'path-to-file.jpg', Single_Blob) as Image1)
           ,26
           ,(SELECT BulkColumn 
            FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'path-to-file.jpg', Single_Blob) as Image2)
            ,'Group123'
           ,'GroupABC')
```