# How Do You Save An Image Out of a SQL Database Into the File System Using only SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, image, sql-server-2008

Similar to this question only the other way of flow.

[Insert Picture into SQL Server 2005 Image Field using only SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416881/insert-picture-into-sql-server-2005-image-field-using-only-sql)

I need to be able to save a image field out into the file system and be able to name the file with only using SQL. I don't want to use TEXTCOPY either because I need to use the connection to the database that is running the query itself.

I'd like this to work in SQL 2005 to support older database clients but if it's available in only 2008 that's fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: No, using SSIS would also require creating a new connection from the one running the query. I need to do it so I can put it within a single stored procedure if possible.

Comment: Why would the new connection matter, and you can create an Agent job to run the package, then start the job from an SP.

Comment: Some of my clients use express and don't have an Agent installed (or a 3rd party equivlant), so I was looking for ways around requiring that as well. It is a good method though. New connection matters because I don't want to supply login credentials.

Comment: Can you use a clr function ? that would cover 2005/8

Comment: Some could be using mixed and some could be using only SQL, so I am limited by the later.
Yes I could do CLR, but I am unsure if I could do it that way without creating another connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL 2k8 there is the new [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) type that covers such cases. Filestreams can be opened via the Win32 file access handle like any other file, but hey are integrated into the database from transaction and backup/restore point of view.

I had a similar issue in SQL 2k5 and my solution was to use a CLR stored procedure with EXTERNAL_ACCESS that was writing into the file system using C# file operations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to save out using only sql, but there is a command-line utility, [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646(SQL.80).aspx).

Comment: Yes, bcp is near the same to TEXTCOPY. An external executable that connects to the database via login info that needs to be provided. The reason I do not want to do this is I do not want to store login information inside the text of a stored procedure.