# Android Upload Image To Mysql

Tags: android, upload, mysql

Good Evening.I googled all the way down all time and by my surprise i found out that actually you cannot upload image to mysql server as because it won't show it.I hardly believe to it but here is my situation.I got servers from amazon(EC2) and got RDS Database as well.Im able to establish conniption to mysql database of amazon and able to send strings to it(mainly words which user typed) and now I'm wondering is it possible to upload an image from android to mysql database and later to retrieve that image from mysql database???any conclusion will be highly appreciated...im developing and it only left one day for me to announce my app.please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* store the image in a MySQL database using a `BLOB` data type.  See this answer here:

[Images in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665730/images-in-mysql)

However, this is not always the best decision in terms of performance.  One of the suggested solutions is to upload the image to a server and store the location of the image in the MySQL database instead of storing the actual image data.

Comment: I understood you and I'm so thanks full for any information but please can you tell me how do it because I'm using amazon servers and i have no clue how to upload on image,lets say I'm an android developer and got no clue about php or mysql,i only manage to have connection to mysql and store some php codes on server to accept values of characters which typed by user:)