# PHP image upload issue using xampp localhost

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, xampp, localhost

I have written the following code to upload an image into the database, however, everytime I choose an image and press "upload" all I get is "Waiting for localhost" and nothing loads on the browser. I'm using xampp for my localhost. The database name is "votingsystem" and the table to insert the image is "photo".

After running this php file I am also unable to run other php files since they all exhibit the same problem on the browser by saying "Waiting for localhost" when trying to run them. As such I have to restart my file editor and run it again. It's been a recurring problem.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: user1
 * Date: 10-Jul-15
 * Time: 9:19 PM
 */

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("votingsystem") or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['Upload']))
{
    $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if(!isset($file))
    {
        echo "Please select an image.";
    }

    else
    {
        $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

        if($image_size == FALSE)
        {
            echo "That's not an image";
        }

        else
        {
            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo VALUES ('', '999', '$image_name', '$image')");

            if(!$insert)
            {
                echo "Problem uploading image!";
            }

            else
            mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
        }

    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Image Upload</title>
    </head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image.css">

    <body>

        <form action="image.php" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type = "file" name = "image">
            </br>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Upload">

        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) (`addslashes()` is **NOT** a defense), and storing the `tmp_name` is pointless. it exists only for the life of the script, and then PHP auto-deletes the temporary file. plus, checking for filenames is NOT proper upload validation. there's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Images in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665730/images-in-mysql)

Comment: another thing is that after running this php file, i cannot run other php files as well. They all keep showing "waiting for localhost" and nothing loads on the screen for them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason to try to save the whole image into database? I would suggest to consider **saving the image as file** on the server, while **keeping only the filename in the database**.

The reasons for this are numerous, the most important one being big saving in database size and untouched performance.

In contrast, saving the whole file inside the database table would probably mean *huge database size* and consequently bring about a significant **drop in performance**.

So, if you decide to follow this proposed approach, the flow in your PHP code might be:

1. Get the uploaded image
2. Check/validate it
3. Move it to your destination folder (it is strongly advised to use
   the *move_uploaded_file()* function for this due to improved
   security). The destination folder should be visible by the browser, i.e. is under your web root.
4. Update your database table with the filename and relative path to the newly
   stored image.

Maybe this quick article would aid you: 
http://davidwalsh.name/basic-file-uploading-php (I'm not the author).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Storing-Images-in-MySQL-with-PHP.html
as @Marc B said doesn't have any sense to use `addslashes()` more if you are calling the PHP variable $_FILES.