# Insert an image in SQL Server 2000 without a frontend?

Tags: sql, image, insert, sql-server-2000

I want to insert a .jpg image into SQL server using simple INSERT query.

I tried the following query in which was posted as an answer to the following question 
[Insert Picture into SQL Server 2005 Image Field using only SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416881/insert-picture-into-sql-server-2005-image-field-using-only-sql)

In my case I modified the query as follows

```
INSERT INTO iffcar
                      (name, address, idno, barcode, Photo)
SELECT     'ishan', 'hohn', 100, 'barcodedmessage', BulkColumn
FROM         OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\use.jpg', Single_Blob) AS iffcarPicture
```

now I am getting the error as

[image]

My table structure is as follows

[image]

Please help me to resolve the error.

Comment: What is your photo Column defined as? can you provide the table create stmt?

Comment: Are you definitely on SQL Server 2005 not SQL Server 2000? Enterprise Manager is a 2000 tool.

Comment: @ Martin Very sorry very very sorry, it is not 2005 but 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this MSSQL tip](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1643):

> The BULK option was added to T-SQL in
>   SQL Server 2005 and it persists in SQL
>   Server 2008. When using SQL Server
>   2000 it was possible to read and write
>   to the file system using the
>   sp_OA_Create and sp_OA_Method extended
>   stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

When i run this on my local server defining the photo as Varbinary(max) it works, when i define it as Varbinary(500) it get an Error, did you define it in your Create statement as Varbinary(500)? try using the same definition form the question you linked, and add the Columns you need in addition.