# How to create an image column in a SQL Server table and retrieve it in ASP.NET using VB

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I want to know how to create an image column in a SQL Server table and retrieve it in ASP.NET using VB.NET

```
create table Tbl(ID int primary key,Name varchar(20),Image ....)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [VARBINARY(MAX)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) to store this data.

As to the code side, [here is a good, brief answer.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/b818de10-9dbb-4ca4-9c31-8f3305713eee/)

From the answer:

```
FileStream st = new FileStream(@"C:\filename.jpg", FileMode.Open);
byte[] buffer = new byte[st.Length];
st.Read(buffer, 0, (int)st.Length);
st.Close();

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("...");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "UPDATE SomeTable SET image=@image WHERE ID = 1", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", buffer);
conn.Open();
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: pllz Justin how can i directly add an image in sql column without usin any VB method ?

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2007/09/26/Insert-binary-data-like-images-into-SQL-Server-without-front-end.aspx

Comment: i want to insert the image in a column of a table alredy have a 5 columns 
i try this but it does not work 
insert into dbo.Produit values('Pc portable','HP EliteBook série p','Un ordinateur professionnel robuste de 35,5 et 39,6 cm (14.0" et 15.6") à fonctions multiples, hautes performances et longue autonomie',SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\Yassine-Kira\Desktop\Templates\ProductImg\elite-book_tcm_133_1096796.png', SINGLE_BLOB) ,20,4999,0);

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416881/insert-picture-into-sql-server-2005-image-field-using-only-sql

Answer (score 1):

[Save and Retrieve Files from SQL Server Database using ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-Files-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx)

[Storing and Retrieving Images/Files In Sql Server - VB.NET](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29583-Storing-Retrieving-Files-In-Sql-Server.aspx)

Comment: pllz JotaBa how can i directly add an image in sql without usin any VB method ?

Answer (score 0):

in the sql server create the column with type: `image`.
and in the asp, use this example code: (it's in c#)

```
    string con = "your connection string"
    var Image =  (from A in YourTblImage
                  select A).First();//to get one record of the table use the `first`
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"yourPath to save the image", FileMode.Create);
    try
    {

        System.Data.Linq.Binary img = image.imageColumnName;
        byte[] imageK = img.ToArray();
        fs.Write(imageK, 0, imageK.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string str = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Comment: tnkks my bro ^^
i want to insert the image in a column of a table alredy have a 5 columns 
i try this but it does not work 
insert into dbo.Produit values('Pc portable','HP EliteBook série p','Un ordinateur professionnel robuste de 35,5 et 39,6 cm (14.0" et 15.6") à fonctions multiples, hautes performances et longue autonomie',SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\Yassine-Kira\Desktop\Templates\ProductImg\elite-book_tcm_133_1096796.png', SINGLE_BLOB) ,20,4999,0);