# MySQL Image insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, blob

G'day I was just wondering how I could insert an image to a database. I've created a table that has already existing data for every column, and I've added an "Image" column, how would I insert an image to a particular row?

Comment: What language you will use?

Comment: Read This before you go ahead : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/what-about-storing-images-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

You do *not* want to do it this way. Rather, use the filesystem for what it's good for -- storing data. Have the names for the image and what they correspond to in your SQL tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
  Id int,
  Name varchar(50) not null,
  Photo varbinary(max) not null
)


INSERT INTO Employees (Id, Name, Photo) 
  SELECT 10, 'John', BulkColumn 
  FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\photo.bmp', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture
```

Comment: What do I write after FROM?

Comment: `OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Image\image.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS import` . All the 3 lines can be at one line... you just need to change the image path `C:\Image\image.jpg`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(BULK N'E:\TheClash.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB)' at line 3

Comment: I didnt test, try this and say me if it works: `INSERT INTO YourTable (YourVarbinaryColumn) VALUES ((SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'E:\Imagem.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS A))`

Comment: Still the same error. Does is matter if the column is set to 'Blob'?

Comment: I found another question like your: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416881/insert-picture-into-sql-server-2005-image-field-using-only-sql look at the correct response... try it...

Comment: I've found a way in PHP MyAdmin to upload an image using a form. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Great, so, post your answer and mark it as the best answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's the PHP way:

```
$fileblob =file_get_contents("path/to/imagefile");
$cleandata=addslashes($fileblob);


$sql="update mytable set blobcolumn='$cleandata' where pkcol=$mypkvalue";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

hd1 has a good point; the filesystem is better at handling image objects - and it will be faster for users to retrieve and cache the object.

However to answer it you need to store it in a blob ddatatype.  (Binary large object).  Remember to escape the source before importing it into your database, and un-escaping it on retrieval.

INSERT INTO table (`blobcolumn`) VALUES (...blob contents here...);